# How can I attain deuterons using a proton accelerator?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I'm in high school and I had read in this paper https://cds.cern.ch/record/849079/files/thesis-2005-033.pdf

That deuterons can be better in spallation process. I was curious how we can use the proton accelerator to get deuterons? Since protons are easy to made it can be most viable way to produce deuterons from an accelerator. Can someone answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium  deuterium is naturally found as naturally as hydrogen. No need for accelerators to make deuterons.

Comment: Yeap! I know that! I was asking, Accelerator driven method as it's logical way to create a beam of deutrons. Do you know how it can be done?

Comment: You can use deuterium gas instead of hydrogen gas and voila, you accelerate dexterous instead of protons.